# Bug: Hover is changing link href, Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, hover

I have a link which contains several images. Upon hovering an interval is set and css class is added, and iterated over the images. Upon mouse out the interval is cleared. Code below:

```
jQuery('#flicker').hover(
    function() {
       flicker = setInterval(function() {
           if (jQuery('#flicker img.active').next('img').length > 0) {
               jQuery('#flicker img.active').removeClass('active').next('img').addClass('active');
           } else {
               jQuery('#flicker img').removeClass('active');
               jQuery('#flicker img:first-child').addClass('active');
           } 
       }, 200);
     }, 
     function() {
       clearInterval(flicker);
     }
 );
```

For some reason on Internet Explorer 6,7,8 the link href changes on hover, to a string of numbers.

For a test case see [here](http://www.stighlorgan.com/dev/test.html). Any help greatly appreciated, I've not seen this bug before!

Thanks.

( Also let me know if you can't replicate, I'm testing on a Mac using Parallels. )

Comment: Its working fine for me on all browsers.

Comment: Then that should have been mentioned in the question like - "My respected SO peers, I have corrected the code, but still if you wish, please make it more correct, post comments, give answers, but dont forget, the code is correct :P"

Comment: Sorry, for clarity the test link is now as the above code.

Comment: @T.J. - but that created a lot of chaos. :P :D

Comment: @Coding: Indeed. :-) (And we should probably clean up the comments, they no longer add anything.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you called the variable in which you store the interval timer `flicker`, which is also the `id` of your element, and you haven't declared the variable and so you fall prey to the [Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). On IE (and some other browsers) `id` values end up being properties on the `window` object (the value being the `Element`), so you're ending up assigning a number to the element, which on IE sets its "default" property, which is `href`.

Just create a private context and declare your `flicker` variable:

```
(function() {
    var flicker = 0;

    jQuery('#flicker').hover(
        function() {
           flicker = setInterval(function() {
               if (jQuery('#flicker img.active').next('img').length > 0) {
                   jQuery('#flicker img.active').removeClass('active').next('img').addClass('active');
                   } else {
                   jQuery('#flicker img').removeClass('active');
                   jQuery('#flicker img:first-child').addClass('active');
               } 
           }, 200);
         }, 
         function() {
           clearInterval(flicker);
         }
     ); 
})();
```

---

**Off-topic**: Some other changes I'd recommend:

- Every time you call the `jQuery` function, a fair bit of work has to be done, so calling it repeatedly for the same selector when the document hasn't changed is fairly inefficient. It's one of those patterns that should raise a red flag in your mind when you see it. Recommend updating the hover code to store and reuse the result. (Mind you, it runs just fine on IE7 which isn't exactly a fast browser, so...)
- Recommend clearing the `flicker` variable when you clear the timer. `0` is a good value, because `0` is not a valid timer handle. (That's why I used it as the initial value above.) Just in case something weird happens with the browser calling your functions.

Comment: Bingo, thanks. Call me stupid but why would setting a variable with the same name as the ID i'm listening for the hover event on change the href?

Comment: @addedlovely: I've added a bit to the answer to explain.

Comment: Hi T.J, yeah interestings I did cache the jQuery function on some earlier code, but ran some test on jsperf and this was quicker. Let me just double check that, as its seems un intuitive.  Re setting flicker to 0 is that not what clear interval does?

Comment: @addedlovely: `clearInterval` will cancel the interval, but it doesn't have any effect on your `flicker` variable (it can't, JavaScript is a purely pass-by-value language, so all `clearInterval` sees is the *value* of the variable, not the variable itself).